# Userjs in Opera. What about jQuery?

Tags: opera, jquery

Does it work, if I specify a folder for Operas userjs and that folder contains jQuery.js? Can I then use jQuery in my own scripts?

Answer (score 2):

No, don't do that. Not raw and unchecked at least.

It won't work and what you'll find is that sites that already use jQuery may [take forever to load nothing but an expectant blank page](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/pages-stay-blank-with-1-3-1-being-a-userjs-on-opera).

You can try and throw a check around your `jquery.js` file in your userscripts directory like so:

```
 if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

    //the jquery.js file is here

 }
```

That should stop the conflict of having two jQuery libraries loaded on the one page.

No guarantees that that will work though.

Answer (score 0):

Or use [jQuery No Conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```